# Chart.js with Typescript access first iteration of object

Tags: typescript, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am having a lot of trouble with this, I have four sets of datasets all in an list of objects and I can't seem to figure out how to access the first one, I am pretty new to typescript. What I am trying to do is be able to press a button and then switch between the datasets.

```
export type LineType = {

    labels: string[];
    datasets: {
        label: string;
        data: number[];
        fill: boolean;
        borderColor: string;
        tension: number;
    }[];
}

//first dataset config
      const config1: LineType = { 
        labels: chartData.labels,
        datasets: chartData.datasets[0] //i am getting an error here
      }

//when i do "datasets: chartData.datasets" i am able to access the last dataset

//datasets 
export default {
    /* marketData datasets[0] */
      labels: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Fannie Mae", 
          data: [5, 6, 7, 8],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "Freddie Mac", 
          data: [9, 10, 11, 12],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'red',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "Mortgage Bankers Association", 
          data: [8, 12, 6, 7],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'purple',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "National Association of Realtors", 
          data: [4, 7, 3, 0],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'green',
          tension: 0.1
        }],
    /* forecastRates datasets[1]*/
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Fannie Mae", 
            data: [3.5, 4.0, 4.7, 5.2],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "Freddie Mac", 
            data: [4.0, 4.7, 5.2, 6.0],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'red',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "Mortgage Bankers Association", 
            data: [4.2, 5.5, 5.8, 6.5],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'purple',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "National Association of Realtors", 
            data: [3.2, 6.3, 7.3, 6.5],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'green',
            tension: 0.1
          }],
    /* forecastOrignations datasets[2]*/
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Fannie Mae", 
          data: [100, 200, 300, 400],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "Freddie Mac", 
          data: [500, 600, 400, 300],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'red',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "Mortgage Bankers Association", 
          data: [400, 500, 580, 650],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'purple',
          tension: 0.1
        },
        {
          label: "National Association of Realtors", 
          data: [320, 630, 730, 650],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'green',
          tension: 0.1
        }],
      /* orignations datasets[]*/ 
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Fannie Mae", 
            data: [100, 200, 300, 700],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "Freddie Mac", 
            data: [333, 666, 555, 444],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'red',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "Mortgage Bankers Association", 
            data: [543, 631, 713, 323],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'purple',
            tension: 0.1
          },
          {
            label: "National Association of Realtors", 
            data: [433, 655, 733, 655],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'green',
            tension: 0.1
          }]
  
  }
```

the error I am getting is "Type '{ label: string; data: number[]; fill: boolean; borderColor: string; tension: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ label: string; data: number[]; fill: boolean; borderColor: string; tension: number; }[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more" I have been stuck on this problem for a few days and can't seem to figure it out. Ant help would be appreciated